# Translating ip route add into netplan

Tags: ethernet, netplan, 22.10

Would you please help me with one simple question. I would like to have persistent route in my network settings.

How can I reproduce this command in netplan (Ubuntu 22.10):

> sudo ip route add 10.0.10.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp3s0

I just get messed with all these YAML markup. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use routes to and from, see below,

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [<your IP>/24]
      routes:
        - to: 10.0.10.0/24
          via: 10.0.0.1
          metric: 100
```

I would also advise using netplan try when making routing edits as if your remoted and muck up something you can get locked out.

Comment: Thank you very much. My pc obtains ip address from dhcp. Will this work?

dhcp4: true

adresses:[10.0.0.0/24]

Comment: It should, I've only ever used it with static networks though.